poetry update doesn't update outdated
I have

Python 3.11
poetry 1.7.1

When I do the command
poetry show --outdated

it shows me a list of libraries outdates, also myPy:

but when I do
poetry update mypy


nothing happens, output is:
 Updating dependencies
 Resolving dependencies... (0.3s)
 No dependencies to install or update


And this is my pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
black = "~24.1.1"
flake8 = "~7.0.0"
isort = "~5.13.2"
mypy = "~1.8.0"

I've changed this mypy = "~1.8.0" into mypy = "~1.8"
following this guide:
Tilde requirements Python Poetry
but nothing has changed.
What I am missing ?

The version range for mypy is restricted to ~1.8.0 in your pyproject.toml. This means only versions >=1.8.0,<1.9.0 are allowed.
poetry update updates the locked version within this given range.
What you probably want is to change the version range to ^1.8.0 which means >=1.8.0, <2.0.

thank you ! I' ve actually replied to my self with the same answer ! ahaha

After investigating more, I've realized that
the pyproject.tom has the "tilde" requirements,
whilst, if I want to update the library, I should use
the called "caret requirement"
Caret requirement poetry
I've changed the pyproject.toml into this:
mypy = "^1.8.0"

and now the command
poetry update mypy

works !
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals

  • Updating mypy (1.8.0 -> 1.10.0)


